# Can't install modules with pip

Tags: python, numpy, installation, pip

This seems like a common problem that has been asked many times on different forums but I cannot seems to get any solution to work on my machine.

I am using Windows 10 Enterprise and Python 3.9.0.

When I use `pip install numpy` I receive the following error message:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1122)'))': /simple/numpy/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1122)'))': /simple/numpy/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1122)'))': /simple/numpy/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1122)'))': /simple/numpy/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1122)'))': /simple/numpy/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/numpy/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/numpy/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1122)'))) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy
```

One proposed solution is to create a pip.ini file in `C:\ProgramData\pip` with the following contents:

```
[global] trusted-host = pypi.python.org
pypi.org
files.pythonhosted.org
```

If I try `pip install numpy` I get the following message:

```
Configuration file could not be loaded.
Source contains parsing errors: 'C:\\ProgramData\\pip\\pip.ini'
        [line  2]: 'pypi.org\n'
        [line  3]: 'files.pythonhosted.org'
```

I have also tried `python.exe -m pip install -U numpy  --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org' from the command line.  This also fails and gives me the following message:

```
Collecting numpy
  Using cached numpy-1.19.2.zip (7.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\blilley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe' 'C:\Users\blilley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\blilley\AppData\Local\Temp\1\tmphsrjyfjg'
         cwd: C:\Users\blilley\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-install-mctformt\numpy
    Complete output (200 lines):
    Running from numpy source directory.
    setup.py:470: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
      run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
    Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pxd.in
    Processing numpy/random\bit_generator.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\mtrand.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_bounded_integers.pyx.in
    Processing numpy/random\_common.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_generator.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_mt19937.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_pcg64.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_philox.pyx
    Processing numpy/random\_sfc64.pyx
    Cythonizing sources
    blas_opt_info:
    blas_mkl_info:
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    customize MSVCCompiler
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Users\\blilley\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\blilley\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    blis_info:
      libraries blis not found in ['C:\\Users\\blilley\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\blilley\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\blilley\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\blilley\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\libs']
    get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
    customize GnuFCompiler
    Could not locate executable g77
    Could not locate executable f77
    customize IntelVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable ifort
    Could not locate executable ifl
    customize AbsoftFCompiler
    Could not locate executable f90
    customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable DF
    customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
    Could not locate executable efl
    customize Gnu95FCompiler
    Could not locate executable gfortran
    Could not locate executable f95
    customize G95FCompiler
    Could not locate executable g95
    customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
    customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
    Could not locate executable efort
    Could not locate executable efc
    customize PGroupFlangCompiler
    Could not locate executable flang
    don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries tatlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\blilley\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\blilley\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_info:
      libraries satlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\blilley\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\blilley\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\blilley\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\blilley\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_info:
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\blilley\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\blilley\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    accelerate_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\blilley\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-install-mctformt\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
        Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
        Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
        A better performance should be easily gained by switching
        Blas library.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
    blas_info:
      libraries blas not found in ['C:\\Users\\blilley\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\blilley\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\blilley\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-install-mctformt\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
        the BLAS environment variable.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
    blas_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\blilley\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-install-mctformt\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1914: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
        the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
      if self._calc_info(blas):
      NOT AVAILABLE

    non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
    lapack_opt_info:
    lapack_mkl_info:
      libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Users\\blilley\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\blilley\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_lapack_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\blilley\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\blilley\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_clapack_info:
      libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\blilley\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\blilley\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    flame_info:
      libraries flame not found in ['C:\\Users\\blilley\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\blilley\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\blilley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\blilley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\blilley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\libs
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\blilley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_info:
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\blilley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\blilley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\blilley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\libs
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\blilley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\blilley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\blilley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\blilley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\libs
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\blilley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\blilley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\blilley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\blilley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\libs
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\blilley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_info:
      libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\blilley\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\blilley\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\blilley\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-install-mctformt\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1748: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\blilley\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-install-mctformt\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1748: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
      NOT AVAILABLE

    numpy_linalg_lapack_lite:
      FOUND:
        language = c
        define_macros = [('HAVE_BLAS_ILP64', None), ('BLAS_SYMBOL_SUFFIX', '64_')]

    C:\Users\blilley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\distutils\dist.py:274: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running dist_info
    running build_src
    build_src
    building py_modules sources
    creating build
    creating build\src.win-amd64-3.9
    creating build\src.win-amd64-3.9\numpy
    creating build\src.win-amd64-3.9\numpy\distutils
    building library "npymath" sources
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Build Tools for Visual Studio": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\blilley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe' 'C:\Users\blilley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\blilley\AppData\Local\Temp\1\tmphsrjyfjg' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Numpy Installation for Python Ver-3.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64237904/numpy-installation-for-python-ver-3-9)

Comment: tl;dr. numpy isn't available for 3.9 yet, which has only just been released. Downgrade to 3.8 instead.

Comment: Well, the last error is not pip error. It starts with "don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'" after looking for several executables.

Comment: The `Configuration file could not be loaded.` part is because there is a formatting error in specifying multiple hosts; Hosts should be separated by spaces not new line

Comment: Thanks all.  Turns out my issues were a combination of problems - the missing wheels story for Python 3.9 and an over eager corporate firewall.  I reverted back to python 3.8 and set up the pip.ini thing to get around the SSL message.