# Unexpected Error while install numpy 1.18.5

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am trying to install NumPy version 1.18.4 using having pip on windows 11 but it ends with the following error:

Pyton version: 3.9.9

> Collecting numpy==1.18.5
> Using cached numpy-1.18.5.zip (5.4 MB)
> Installing build dependencies ... done
> Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
> Preparing wheel metadata ... error
> ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
> command: 'C:\Users\HP1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe' 'C:\Users\HP1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517\in_process_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\HP1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpjjy7i1_a'
> cwd: C:\Users\HP1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3rab2zjy\numpy_40bc65e470ac4ab58a3c63d4b8434f30
> Complete output (199 lines):
> Running from numpy source directory.
> setup.py:461: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command, proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
> run_build = parse_setuppy_commands()
> C:\Users\HP1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3rab2zjy\numpy_40bc65e470ac4ab58a3c63d4b8434f30\tools\cythonize.py:75: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.
> required_version = LooseVersion('0.29.14')
> C:\Users\HP1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3rab2zjy\numpy_40bc65e470ac4ab58a3c63d4b8434f30\tools\cythonize.py:77: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.
> if LooseVersion(cython_version) < required_version:
> Processing numpy/random_bounded_integers.pxd.in
> Processing numpy/random\mtrand.pyx
> Processing numpy/random_bit_generator.pyx
> Processing numpy/random_bounded_integers.pyx.in
> Processing numpy/random_common.pyx
> Processing numpy/random_generator.pyx
> Processing numpy/random_mt19937.pyx
> Processing numpy/random_pcg64.pyx
> Processing numpy/random_philox.pyx
> Processing numpy/random_sfc64.pyx
> Cythonizing sources
> blas_opt_info:
> blas_mkl_info:
> No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
> customize MSVCCompiler
> libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\Users\HP1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib', 'C:\', 'C:\Users\HP1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\libs']
> NOT AVAILABLE

```
blis_info:
  libraries blis not found in ['C:\\Users\\HP1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\HP1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

openblas_info:
  libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\HP1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\HP1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\libs']
get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem', 'flang']'
customize GnuFCompiler
Could not locate executable g77
Could not locate executable f77
customize IntelVisualFCompiler
Could not locate executable ifort
Could not locate executable ifl
customize AbsoftFCompiler
Could not locate executable f90
customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
Could not locate executable DF
customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
Could not locate executable efl
customize Gnu95FCompiler
Could not locate executable gfortran
Could not locate executable f95
customize G95FCompiler
Could not locate executable g95
customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
Could not locate executable efort
Could not locate executable efc
customize PGroupFlangCompiler
Could not locate executable flang
don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries tatlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\HP1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\HP1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_blas_info:
  libraries satlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\HP1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\HP1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\HP1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\HP1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_blas_info:
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['C:\\Users\\HP1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\HP1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

accelerate_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\HP1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3rab2zjy\numpy_40bc65e470ac4ab58a3c63d4b8434f30\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1896: UserWarning:
    Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
    Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
    A better performance should be easily gained by switching
    Blas library.
  if self._calc_info(blas):
blas_info:
  libraries blas not found in ['C:\\Users\\HP1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\HP1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\HP1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3rab2zjy\numpy_40bc65e470ac4ab58a3c63d4b8434f30\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1896: UserWarning:
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
    the BLAS environment variable.
  if self._calc_info(blas):
blas_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\HP1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3rab2zjy\numpy_40bc65e470ac4ab58a3c63d4b8434f30\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1896: UserWarning:
    Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
    the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
  if self._calc_info(blas):
  NOT AVAILABLE

non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
lapack_opt_info:
lapack_mkl_info:
  libraries mkl_rt not found in ['C:\\Users\\HP1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\HP1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

openblas_lapack_info:
  libraries openblas not found in ['C:\\Users\\HP1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\HP1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

openblas_clapack_info:
  libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\HP1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\HP1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

flame_info:
  libraries flame not found in ['C:\\Users\\HP1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\HP1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\HP1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib
  libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\HP1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\HP1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\libs
  libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\Users\HP1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\libs
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_3_10_info:
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\HP1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib
  libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\HP1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\HP1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\libs
  libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\Users\HP1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\libs
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_threads_info:
Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\HP1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\HP1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\HP1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\libs
  libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\HP1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\libs
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

atlas_info:
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\HP1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\HP1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
  libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\Users\HP1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\libs
  libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\Users\HP1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\libs
<class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
  NOT AVAILABLE

lapack_info:
  libraries lapack not found in ['C:\\Users\\HP1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\lib', 'C:\\', 'C:\\Users\\HP1\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python39\\libs']
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\HP1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3rab2zjy\numpy_40bc65e470ac4ab58a3c63d4b8434f30\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1730: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
    Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
    the LAPACK environment variable.
  return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
lapack_src_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\HP1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-3rab2zjy\numpy_40bc65e470ac4ab58a3c63d4b8434f30\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1730: UserWarning:
    Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
    Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
    numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
    the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
  return getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(name))()
  NOT AVAILABLE

C:\Users\HP1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-5wfppmta\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py:275: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
  warnings.warn(msg)
running dist_info
running build_src
build_src
building py_modules sources
creating build
creating build\src.win-amd64-3.9
creating build\src.win-amd64-3.9\numpy
creating build\src.win-amd64-3.9\numpy\distutils
building library "npymath" sources
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
----------------------------------------
```

WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/01/1b/d3ddcabd5817be02df0e6ee20d64f77ff6d0d97f83b77f65e98c8a651981/numpy-1.18.5.zip#sha256=34e96e9dae65c4839bd80012023aadd6ee2ccb73ce7fdf3074c62f301e63120b (from https://pypi.org/simple/numpy/) (requires-python:>=3.5). Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\HP1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe' 'C:\Users\HP1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pip_vendor\pep517\in_process_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\HP1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpjjy7i1_a' Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy==1.18.5 (from versions: 1.3.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.10.0.post2, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.4, 1.11.0, 1.11.1, 1.11.2, 1.11.3, 1.12.0, 1.12.1, 1.13.0rc1, 1.13.0rc2, 1.13.0, 1.13.1, 1.13.3, 1.14.0rc1, 1.14.0, 1.14.1, 1.14.2, 1.14.3, 1.14.4, 1.14.5, 1.14.6, 1.15.0rc1, 1.15.0rc2, 1.15.0, 1.15.1, 1.15.2, 1.15.3, 1.15.4, 1.16.0rc1, 1.16.0rc2, 1.16.0, 1.16.1, 1.16.2, 1.16.3, 1.16.4, 1.16.5, 1.16.6, 1.17.0rc1, 1.17.0rc2, 1.17.0, 1.17.1, 1.17.2, 1.17.3, 1.17.4, 1.17.5, 1.18.0rc1, 1.18.0, 1.18.1, 1.18.2, 1.18.3, 1.18.4, 1.18.5, 1.19.0rc1, 1.19.0rc2, 1.19.0, 1.19.1, 1.19.2, 1.19.3, 1.19.4, 1.19.5, 1.20.0rc1, 1.20.0rc2, 1.20.0, 1.20.1, 1.20.2, 1.20.3, 1.21.0rc1, 1.21.0rc2, 1.21.0, 1.21.1, 1.21.2, 1.21.3, 1.21.4, 1.21.5, 1.22.0rc1, 1.22.0rc2, 1.22.0rc3, 1.22.0, 1.22.1, 1.22.2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy==1.18.5
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.2.4; however, version 22.0.3 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'C:\Users\HP1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Numpy Installation for Python Ver-3.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64237904/numpy-installation-for-python-ver-3-9)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you don't have to use pip my ide is pycharm and there are bult-in packages

not using pip depends on which IDE you are using, For example, you can download pycharm if you don't already have it and you can download the package from pycharm itself.

How you can do that is going to file ➜ Settings ➜ Project ➜ Python Interpreter ➜ and click the + sign over the package label and there you will be able to search for any package you want like numpy

Comment: I am using Command Prompt in windows. I have to install mlagents==0.20.0 for my project and that requires numpy<2.0 but that ends up with the error

Comment: What command did you use to try to install numpy

Comment: I am using ``pip install mlagents==0.20.0`` and it automatically selects the required package

Comment: Instead of doing that try `pip install numpy`

Comment: I tried that but it again gets to Collecting numpy<2.0,>=1.13.3
  Using cached numpy-1.18.5.zip (5.4 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ...

Comment: when trying to install mlagents

Comment: `pip3 install numpy`
or 
`pip3 install mlagents==0.20.0`